# file_get_contents(JSON) not working for valid URL

Tags: php, html, json, decode

I'm trying to get a JSON from a ULR, but I get the error:

**Warning: file_get_contents(http://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?currency=1&appid=730&market_hash_name=StatTrak™ Five-SeveN | Copper Galaxy (Factory New)): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 500 Internal Server Error in F:\Bitnami\htdocs\Dreamweaver\freehtml5streets\updateInventory.php on line 70**

This is the URL I'm trying to use, as you can see if you visit it, it works(you'll have to copy the whole thing):

http://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?currency=1&appid=730&market_hash_name=StatTrak™ Five-SeveN | Copper Galaxy (Factory New)

I have been accessing similar URLs and getting the JSONs, e.g.:

http://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?currency=1&appid=730&market_hash_name=AK-47%20%7C%20Redline%20%28Field-Tested%29

These URLs are basicly the same but the first one doesn't have the HTML tags. Here is my code:

```
        $data = file_get_contents('http://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?currency=1&appid=730&market_hash_name=' . $mydata->market_hash_name);
        $json = json_decode($data);
```

`$mydata->market_hash_name` gets me the section at the end of the URL, but without the HTML tags(%20%) etc.

How can I get this to work?

Comment: It looks like you need to `urlencode($mydata->market_hash_name)`

Comment: I've added an answer to this effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you need to `urlencode` your `$mydata->market_hash_name`, since it uses a number of special and reserved characters.  The following should work:

```
//Assuming $mydata->market_hash_name == "StatTrak™ Five-SeveN | Copper Galaxy (Factory New)"

$data = file_get_contents('http://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?currency=1&appid=730&market_hash_name=' . urlencode($mydata->market_hash_name));
$json = json_decode($data);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may find for some domains that you are unable to use this method ( file_get_contents ) to retrieve a url because the remote server is expecting a valid useragent for example - to my mind it is better to use cURL to get the contents of a remote page....